# Custom processing in webpage which is shown after closing CCT(Chrome custom tab)

Tags: javascript, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

In mobile app we open a page in webview. Now from that page we open CCT (Chrome custom tab). When user click "cross" button in CCT then the parent page is shown again on screen. Now I want to do some custom processing in webapage's code, when this page is shown after clicking CCT cross button. How can I implement this functionality?

NOTE : Need Java script solution as using JS for webpage. Also CCT doesn't support overriding the functionality of cross button.

Tried using `pageshow` event listener on webpage but that is not invoked when CCT is closed.